# Dual boot automatically boots to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, boot, ubuntu-12.10

I wanted to have a dual boot. I have Windows 7 initially installed, then I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in a different partition and now it automatically boots to Ubuntu 12.10 without having a boot menu. Now, I don't know how I can go back to Windows 7. Please help me, how can I see the boot menu that allows me to choose which OS to load?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the grub menu (/etc/grub.d/40_custom) : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1817827

Something like this:  (modify it for the partition where your Windows 7 is installed)

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" {    
    insmod ntfs    
    set root='(hd0,2)'    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 6040b5fb40b5d7cc    
    chainloader +1 
}
```

Comment: Okay, the menu shows up but the problem is I can't see Windows 7 in the choices. Is the fact that it was encrypted a factor why I can't see it? If so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First you change the GRUB configuration:

nano / etc / default / grub

GRUB_TIMEOUT = 10

Where are the seconds value 10 appears to boot menu.

GRUB after upgrade

sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

You can repair MBR using a Windows 7 installation USB/DVD 
On command prompt:

**bootsect /nt60 all**

This will allow you to boot to Windows 7 again.

To add Ubuntu to Windows boot menu see [Dual boot Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu, Fedora etc.)](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html)